# Comparing and Inserting from a string to Linked List

Tags: c, string, data-structures, linked-list

I have to compare

"5-5-0"

"5-5-1"

At first the first digits then the second the digit finally the last digit in order to find the right place so that I can embed it to my linked list.

Can you help me out?

To be more precise: I read a file.
That file contains some string and some integer.For the first string part, I have to find a place for my new Node to insert.
For example;

"3-0-0"
"3-2-1"

User enters "3-1-1".I have to create a linked list node then insert this node to between this two string.

So far I've tried *atoi* and *strcmp* but couldn't managed it.

Comment: can you paste the code you have tried and the problem you have, so that we can help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  We can't help you if you don't show the code you've tried.  Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]) of your best effort so far, and then maybe we'll be able to help you.  We don't write code from scratch for you; we do help you fix your efforts, as long as they're a reasonably honest attempt.

Comment: If the numbers around the `-`-signs do not exceed `9`, i.e. do not become two or more digits long, `strcmp` should actually give you the right order. Why did it not work?

Comment: will the numbers in the strings be single digit numbers? if they are, then the procedure to solve this should be rather simple; but if they are not, then the procedure will be more lengthy - and will depend on how you want to compare the numbers (i.e- according to their values, or lexicographically).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generalized answer to your problem.

Is this what you're looking for?

And yes, it's enough to use strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
** List macros
*/

#define LNEXT(list_cell)            ((list_cell)->next)
#define LTONEXT(list_cell)          ((list_cell) = LNEXT(list_cell))
#define LCONT(list_cell, t_type)    ((t_type)((list_cell)->content))
#define LSTR(list_cell)             LCONT(list_cell, char*)

typedef struct      s_list
{
    void            *content;
    size_t          content_size;
    struct s_list   *next;
}                   t_list;

/*
** Helpers
*/

void    *ft_memdup(void const *ptr, size_t size)
{
    void            *result;

    result = (void*)malloc(size);
    if (result == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    memcpy(result, ptr, size);
    return (result);
}

/*
** List functions
*/

t_list  *ft_lstnew(void const *content, size_t content_size)
{
    t_list  *result;

    result = (t_list*)malloc(sizeof(t_list));
    if (result == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    result->next = NULL;
    if (content == NULL)
    {
        result->content = NULL;
        result->content_size = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        result->content = ft_memdup(content, content_size);
        result->content_size = content_size;
    }
    return (result);
}

/*
** Recives a pointer to a comparison function
*/

void    ft_lstinsert(
            t_list **head,
            t_list *new_l,
            t_list *prev,
            int (*cmp)(void*, void*))
{
    if (*head == NULL)
        *head = new_l;
    else if (cmp((*head)->content, new_l->content) > 0)
    {
        new_l->next = *head;
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = new_l;
        else
            *head = new_l;
    }
    else
        ft_lstinsert(&(LNEXT(*head)), new_l, *head, cmp);
}

/*
** Iterates through all nodes, and apply function f
*/

void    ft_lstiter(t_list *lst, void (*f)(t_list *elem))
{
    while (lst)
    {
        f(lst);
        lst = lst->next;
    }
}

void    print_node(t_list *node)
{
    printf("%s\n", LSTR(node));
}

void    add_str(t_list **head, char *buf)
{
    ft_lstinsert(head,
        ft_lstnew(buf, strlen(buf)),
        NULL,
        (int (*)(void*, void*))(&strcmp));
}

int             main()
{
    t_list  *head;

    head = NULL;
    add_str(&head, "5-5-1");
    add_str(&head, "5-5-0");
    add_str(&head, "5-5-3");
    add_str(&head, "5-5-2");
    add_str(&head, "1-5-3");

    ft_lstiter(head, &print_node);
}
```

Producing the following result:

```
1-5-3
5-5-0
5-5-1
5-5-2
5-5-3
```